# I want to store N values into an array with the values filled sequentially starting from 1

Tags: java, arrays

I want to generate N integer values where `N = row * column` (some coordinates from a 2D plane) into an array. Then I want to assign values from 1 through N into the array sequentially from left to right, and then return the array.

```
private static int[] to1Dcoords(int row, int column) {
    grid = new int[row][column];                           //creates n by n grid
    int temp = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[row].length; column++) {
            grid[row][column] = temp;
            temp++;
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

This image should clarify what I am trying to do

[image]

input `to1Dcoords(2,3)`
output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you draw an example? (given input -> expected output)

Comment: 1) you do not assign values to 2D array sequentially - you'll get `ArrayOutOfBoundsIndexException` in the line `grid[row][column] = temp;`  2) if you need to populate 1D array with values from 1 to `row*column` you do not need to create 2D array at all.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: you also don't need to have a separate variable temp and increased in every loop, since that code can work with just  a single loop you can use a for loop and use the iterator variable to fill the values sequentially.

Comment: It seems to me that your code is doing that, except that you are not using `i` or `j` to index into the array. That's probably it. Don't use some `row` or `column` outside the scope, it's not necessary. Don't forget to change `column++` to `j++`.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to create a 1D array with increasing numbers in the array, you can do that without the intermediate 2D array.

```
private static int[] to1Dcoords(int row, int column) {
    int[] result = new int[row*column];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```